How to set a symbol to be commutative?
ccr = a ** ad :> ad ** a + 1
comm[A_, B_] := ExpandAll[A ** B - B ** A //. ccr];
these two commands should be enough to reproduce
comm[a, ad]
returning 1
but the command
comm[a g, ad]
should return g and it doesn't. Because mathematica assumes g is not commutative. So far I have been unprotecting and overriding NumberQ like so
NumberQ[g] = 0
to get the requried behaviour. but somehow this is causing other problems with the kernel. Is there another way?

Try SetAttributes[f, Orderless]; where f is your commutative operation.

Might find some useful approaches here or here. Other possibilities: 1 2 3 (see section "Some noncommutative algebraic manipulation"). Granted, there is overlap in all these.

@yarchik hmm that doesnt work because comm[a,b] = -comm[b,a] is a defining feature of the commutator. I thought you meant set g to orderless but that also just does not work

Perhaps you can rely on the newish tensor capabilities for this. For example:
ccr = a . ad :> ad . a + 1;
comm[A_,B_] := Simplify[TensorExpand[A.B - B.A, Assumptions -> g ∈ Reals] /. ccr]

Then:
comm[a, ad]
comm[a g, ad]


1


g


This answers the question but one might imagine similar questions arising wherein the thrust is not to produce a commutator but rather a canonicalization. For the simple example here one might do like so: `In[89]:= canonicalize[a_ . b_] := a . b /. ccr
canonicalize[a . ad]
Out[90]= 1 + ad . a`. How well this might generalize will depend on the actual needs though (and perhaps canonicalization isn't even one of them).

I expected this to work for comm[a, ad . ad] but somehow it doesn't. The expected result here is 2ad but it doesn't apply the rule repeatedly

Also somehow 1.a does not simplify, it seems I would have to do the same amount of development as if I was using **

Does replace repeated work for you?

A mathematica package Quantum Notaion can be used to evaluate commutative relationship, this package is created for quantum computation, it include most common function in quantum mechanics. But i don't know why the website cannot open  again (i live in China), i has this package because i download it before. If you cannot open this website, i could send you this package use email. The package use is simple, when you add on this package is completed, you can load this package and define some relationship base on you need, like this:
A short introduce can be find in wechat article.



This doesn't answer OP's specific question. 2. Please post code text rather than screenshot only. 3. The page can be found by wayback machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20190702030717/http://homepage.cem.itesm.mx/lgomez/quantum/


I apologize for my unclear response. I’ll make sure to avoid these mistakes as much as possible in the future.

Is it possible to do normal ordering with this package?

i mean is there a way to make it write operators in a canonical order with creation operators to the left? So instead of ad . a + a.ad it would write 1 + 2 ad.a

Yes, it can be done. Once the package is installed on your computer, you can follow these steps: 1. Load the package by executing the command Needs["QuantumNotation"].
2. Define "a" as a quantum symbol using SetQuantumObject[a].
3. Establish the commutation relation ([a, a^\dagger] = 1).

To evaluate the expression 'a.adag + adag.a', you will notice no change if entered directly. However, by using the command CommutatorExpand[a.adag + adag.a], you obtain the result '2a.adag-1'. If you want to obtain the expression '1+2adag.a', it is necessary to include the parameter ReverseOrdering -> True.

Please, see the Update to my answer with the code input and result.
